# There is Not a managed type error when transfer entity to other package?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository

There is spring+jpaRepositories app.

So, PersistenceConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"persistence"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${envConfig}.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"persistence"})
public class PersistenceConfig {
...
}
```

There is tree of directories like this:

```
web
models
      User.java
persistence
      PersistenceConfig.java
      UserRepository.javav
services
```

if locate Entities in model - everything is okey.
If locate entities in persistence - there is error message

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type:
>   class persistence.User

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "User"})})
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
@Id
private int id;
private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `models` package in `ComponentScan`.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"persistence" , "models"})
```

Comment: Problem exists only when transfer from model to persistence. So, it's incorrect to see model - package. I checked - the error is still same

Comment: The last exception you get actually indicates a problem with your JPA setup. "Not a managed bean" means not a type the JPA provider is aware of. If you're setting up a Spring based JPA application I'd recommend to configure the "packagesToScan" property on the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory you have configured to the package that contains your JPA entities. Alternatively you can list all your entity classes in {persistence}.xml, but that's usually more cumbersome

Comment: I found that preconfig for jpa is contains in application.properties line db.entitymanager.packages.to.scan